# How to split array with integers to different format

Tags: php, arrays

I want to split an array having this format:

```
$a = array(10,1234,144,2,101,231,213);
```

To a formatted array like this:

> 10 => 1/0/10.txt
> 1234 => 1/2/3/4/1234.txt
> 144 => 1/4/4/144.txt
> 2 => 2/2.txt
> 101 => 1/0/1/101.txt
> 231 => 2/3/1/231.txt
> 213 => 2/1/3/213.txt

So every integer is split up with a / followed by the original value and a .txt extension. Example: 241 becomes 2/4/1/241.txt.

Comment: Convert the ints to strings and use some loops or explode/implode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the ways that are mentioned above in the answers you can use a loop and get the result that you want as below as well,
I have used [str_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) functions in here.

```
foreach($a as $key=>$val){

        $values =  str_split($val);
        echo implode("/",$values).'/'.$val.'.txt';
        echo "</br>";
}
```

The output will be:

```
1/0/10.txt
1/2/3/4/1234.txt
1/4/4/144.txt
2/2.txt
1/0/1/101.txt
2/3/1/231.txt
2/1/3/213.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```php
$a = [ 10, 1234, 144, 2, 101, 231, 213 ];
$b = [];

foreach( $a as $value ) {
    $chars = implode( '/', str_split( $value ) );

    $b[ $value ] = $chars . '/' . $value . '.txt';
}
```

Then $b should hold the values you need.

I use the short array syntax [], which is available since PHP 5.4, and I personally like it better. But array() works just fine. Documentation on that is here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) to split the number into its digits, then [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to put them back together again as a string separated by `/`, and append the original number and `.txt` to that:

```
$a = array(10,1234,144,2,101,231,213);

$out = array_map(function ($v) {
    return implode('/', str_split($v)) . "/$v.txt";
}, $a);

print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1/0/10.txt
    [1] => 1/2/3/4/1234.txt
    [2] => 1/4/4/144.txt
    [3] => 2/2.txt
    [4] => 1/0/1/101.txt
    [5] => 2/3/1/231.txt
    [6] => 2/1/3/213.txt
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SQn27)